# How to download Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

What are ways to download a Google sheet that you were given access to but don't own?

On https://docs.google.com — is there a Chrome extension or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click 'file'
Go to 'download as'

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Click the file, you will be asked to view only or edit as google docs.
Click view only, at the top page, there are option to open with desktop apps, print file, download and share.

Answer (score 0):

open the file you want to download in google docs itself!!!
for e.g.-
click https://docs.google.com

go to sheets option there...

1. Open for example blank sheet in it...
2. After fully loading you will see "file" option in the upper right corner of your screen click it...
3. You will see a dropdown menu there click down in that dropdown menu you will see "Download as" option click it...
4. You will get six different formats in which you can download that file click on the format you want and click save.